# Помогите найти ошибку в скрипте, который отправляет данные в телеграмм при отправки формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть скрпит, который отправляет данные боту в телеграмм

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".t706 .t-form__submit").click(function() {
function checkFormSuccess() {
if($('.js-form-proccess').hasClass('js-send-form-success')){
var chatid = "********";
var token = "******************************";
var text =
    `СОСТАВ ЗАКАЗА\n`+
    `Номер заказа: ${$('input[name="orderId"]').val()}\n`+
    `Заказ:\n`+
    `${$('.order__product').text()}\n`+
    `Сумма заказа: ${$('.t706__cartwin-totalamount').text()}\n`+
    `${$('input[name="delivery-payment"]').val()}\n`+
    `\n`+
    `ИНФОРМАЦИЯ О КЛИЕНТЕ\n`+
    `Имя: ${$('input[name="name"]').val()}\n`+
    `Телефон: ${$('input[name="phone"]').val()}\n`+
    `Адрес: ${$('input[name="address"]').val()}\n`+
    `Подъезд: ${$('input[name="entrance"]').val()}\n`+
    `Квартира: ${$('input[name="flat"]').val()}\n`+
    `Комментарий к заказу: ${$('textarea[name="comment"]').val()}\n`
  //Отправляем текст в наш телеграм канал
otpravka(token,text,chatid);
function otpravka(token,text,chatid){
var z=$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendMessage?chat_id="+chatid,
data: "parse_mode=HTML&text="+encodeURIComponent(text), 
}); 
};
}
};
});
setTimeout(checkFormSuccess, 500);
});
```

Но он не работает, не могу найти причину. Суть такова, что перед отправкой формы, нужно сделать проверку наличия класса **js-send-form-success** у **js-form-proccess**, при нажатии кнопки отправить **.t-form__submit**, который указывает на успех, а после чего отправлять его телеграмм боту.

Comment: Что конкретно не работает то? Какая ошибка возникает? Что пишет? У вас вопрос без вопроса, вы просто говорите что не работает

Comment: Консоль что-то пишет?